# Intellij: How to disable auto-copied remark symbol?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, markdown

The problem that I have met is when I press enter on the remark or markdown '>' tag, Intellij makes duplicated symbol.

For example, it looks like under.

```
// '|'  is the position of my cursor
// ① create remark
/**
  * |
  */
```

```
// ② press enter
/**
  *
  * |*
  */
```

```
// ③ press enter
/**
  *
  *
  * |* *
  */
```

I've never set or used this option or function before but I think some mistyped key abled this function.
How can I disable this?

Comment: What is your version? It maybe a bug for older IDEA. Unable to reproduce: IDEA 2022.3 EAP (IU-223.4884.69). If inside a `\`\`\`java`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> acts normally. If plain text, then the `*` left to the cursor in the first state is regarded as a <li>, which <kbd>Enter</kbd> will remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for that I didn't mention the version of IDE.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
```

My Intellij version was above like this and running on windows.

I asked to JetBrain and got the reply that it was caused by aws-toolkit plugin.
There was some bug in the plugin. Therefore I disabled aws-tookit and solved the problem.

Here is the issue
https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/3270